# Convertir binario a decimal en Java

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de crear un programa que le permita introducir al usuario mediante consola un numero decimal y convertirlo a binario, y funciona bien pero cuando el usuario ingresa un binario por ejemplo 101010 no se como capturarlo  en una variable ni de que tipo es para poder convertirlo a un decimal, trate de ponerlo como string pero no me lo toma.

Gracias por la ayuda

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class BinaryDecimal {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner reading = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Ingrese un numero decimal o binario");
    
            int decimalNumber = reading.nextInt();
    
            System.out.print(decimalNumber + "\n");
    
    
            if(decimalNumber > 0){
                String binaryNumberTransformed = Integer.toBinaryString(decimalNumber);
                System.out.println("El numero decimal en binario es => " + binaryNumberTransformed);
            }
    
    
            String binaryNumber = reading.next();
    
            if(binaryNumber != null){
                
            }
    
    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo uso esta función:

```
public class BinaryToDecimal{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
        String binaryString="1010";  
        int decimal=Integer.parseInt(binaryString,2);  
        System.out.println(decimal);  
   }
}
```

Con lector por consola:

```
public class BinaryToDecimal{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String binaryString= reader.readLine();
        int decimal=Integer.parseInt(binaryString,2);  
        System.out.println(decimal);
   }
}
```

Comment: Entiendo, pero como leo el 1010 (binario) que coloca el usuario por consola para después convertirlo a decimal yo traté con  String binaryNumber = reading.next(); pero nada, como identifico que el usuario escribió un binario ?

Comment: @JohnOsorio He añadido lo que pides, no lo añadí al inicio ya que pensé que tu problema era solo con la conversión